# currency converter in ruby

Tags: ruby, operators, converters, currency

Been straggling for couple of hours with my work of creating a converter. it should convert from one currency to the other
this is the code:

```
def converter   
  puts "Enter the amount you wish to convert"  
  userAmount = gets   
  puts "Enter your choice: 1 for converting Qatari
  Riyals to US Dollars"   
  puts "Enter your choice: 2 for converting USD ollars to Qatari Riyals"   
  choiceConvert = gets
  while choiceConvert != 1 || choiceConvert != 2 do
    puts "please enter either 1 or 2"
    choiceConvertNew = gets
    choiceConvert = choiceConvertNew   
  end
  if choiceConvert == 1
    convertedAmount = userAmount / 3.65
    puts "Your choice is to convert #{userAmount} Qatari Riyals to US Dollars; 
      You get #{convertedAmount}  US Dollars" 
   else 
     convertedAmount = userAmount * 3.65
     puts "Your choice is to convert #{userAmount} US Dollars to Qatari Riyals; 
       You get #{convertedAmount} Qatari Riyals"  
   end    
end

converter
```

Comment: and what is the problem you face?

Comment: Change `gets` to `gets.to_i` would be a good start. The return value of `gets` is a `String`, including the `\n` for the user pressing Enter.

Comment: To fix the formatting of your code, highlight it an click on the `{}` icon.  One Ruby convention is to use 'camel-case' for class and module names (e.g., `MyClass`) and lowercase for variable and method names (e.g., `choice_convert`).  As @Ivaylo says, you need to be explicit about the problem you have.  If you receive an error message when running your code, you should state the error and where it occurred.  Often it is helpful to include a simple example that shows what output you expect for given input, and what you are getting instead.

Comment: You use `gets` a few times to obtain input from `stdin`. If Ruby executes `str = gets`, it will wait for input.  If you type in `"3.56"` (followed by return or enter), `str` will be set equal to `"3.57\n"`.  If you don't want the newline character (usually the case), change the statement to `str = gets.chomp`.  Then `str` will be `"3.57"`.  If you want to treat this as a float, in order to use it in calculations, change it to `val = gets.chomp.to_f`, so that `val` equals 3.57.  Actually, Ruby is smart enough to allow you just enter `val = gets.to_f`.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to do to much in one place try this

```
def convert_currency(amount,choice)
  converted_amount = choice == 1 ? amount / 3.65 : amount * 3.65
  from, to = choice == 1 ? ["Qatari Riyals", "US Dollars"] : ["US Dollars","Qatari Riyals"]
  puts "Your choice is to convert #{sprintf('%.2f',amount)} #{from} to #{to}; You get #{sprintf('%.2f',converted_amount)} #{to}"
end

puts "Please Enter an Amount"
user_amount = gets.to_f
choice_convert = nil
while ![1,2].include?(choice_convert)
  puts "Enter your choice: 1 for converting Qatari Riyals to US Dollars"
  puts "Enter your choice: 2 for converting US Dollars to Qatari Riyals"
  choice_convert = gets.to_i
end
convert_currency(user_amount,choice_convert)
```

Comment: FYI, if you use `.to_i` and `.to_f` on a `gets`, you don't need `.chomp`. The `.to_i` and `.to_f` will strip the newline out.

Comment: Thanks I don't write much code for user entry like this.(Editted Post)